# Function create in laravel 5.8 does not work

Tags: html, laravel

I am developing a system of quotes with roles and permissions. The method for creating is not working. However, it gives a strange error. When doing the tests, I am able to insert the first record, but it doesn't do it with the following ones. It does not show error at the time of sending the request, it only refreshes the page and does not insert the data.

When trying to do `dd`, it does not show anything, nor does it generate any error. It just refreshes the page.

```
public function create()
{

 $products = product::select('id','name')->orderBy('id')->get();
 $coateds = coated::select('id','name')->orderBy('id')->get();
 $materials = material::select('id','name')->orderBy('id')->get();
 $clients = Client::select('id','name')->orderBy('id')->get();
    return view('admin.quotations.create',compact('products','coateds','materials','clients'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'description'=>'required',
        'price'=>'required',
        'tax'=>'required',
        'subtotal'=>'required',
        'total'=>'required',
        'quantity'=>'required',
        'client_id'=>'required',
        'product_id'=>'required',
        'material_id'=>'required',
        'coated_id'=>'required',

      ]);

     $requestValues = $request->all();
           $quotation = quotation::create([
              'description'=>$requestValues['description'],
              'price'=>$requestValues['price'],
              'tax'=>$requestValues['tax'],
              'subtotal'=>$requestValues['subtotal'],
              'total'=>$requestValues['total'],
              'quantity'=>$requestValues['quantity'],
              'client_id'=>$requestValues['client_id'],
              'product_id'=>$requestValues['product_id'],
              'material_id'=>$requestValues['material_id'],
              'coated_id'=>$requestValues['coated_id'],


            ]);

    return redirect()-> route('admin.quotations.edit', $quotation->id)->with('info','Cotizacion guardada con exito');
}
```

Comment: what error do you get exactly?

Comment: @Nikos M 
It is just the detail is not providing an error, at the time of sending, just refresh the page and do not insert the data, the strange thing was that the first record if I inserted it.

Comment: may be it's a validation error try to dump validation errors in your blade file `{{var_dump($errors->all())}}`

Comment: Pressing the send button just reloads the page, and shows nothing

Comment: inspeccionando la pagina me fije que al darle insertar a los datos genera lo que seria la alerta de error pero la genera vacia 

<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <ul>
      </ul>
</div>

Comment: Have you added attributes to fillable array in your model?

Comment: @RafaelArguelles, Try to include your form html code. You mentioned **'I am able to insert the first record'**. How are you differentiating the individual records? The code setup you have here seems to be for one record.

Comment: The error is not in the code you gave, thats what i can tell